# Handling errors on 200 HTTP response using interceptors

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I have service that integrates with external API. This API is inconsistent and it is unlikely to change.

Inside API there are 2 methods of reporting error, one is response with HTTP 500 code, other is normal 200 HTTP reponse, but with `status` in JSON set to "error".

Handling 500 error is working fine, I have just created interceptor (ngResource interceptor, not $http one) with `responseError` method that will display error message to user when there is any 500 response from API:

```
.factory('ApiErrorHandling', ['ngDialog', function(ngDialog) {
    return {
        responseError: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            var error_dialog = ngDialog.open({
                template: '/api/error.html',
                className: 'error',
                preCloseCallback: function() {
                    if (response.data.status == 'fatal') {
                        window.location.href = '/';
                    } else if (response.data.status == 'error') {
                        var dialogs = ngDialog.getOpenDialogs();
                        for (var i in dialogs) {
                            var dialog = dialogs[i];
                            if (dialog != error_dialog.id) {
                                ngDialog.close(dialog);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                data: {
                    code: response.data.code,
                    status: response.data.status,
                    message: response.data.message,
                    httpCode: response.status,
                }
            });
        },
    }
}])
.factory('ApiMethod', ['$resource', 'ApiErrorHandling', function($resource, ApiErrorHandling) {
    return $resource('/api/method/', {}, {
            query: {method:'POST', interceptor: ApiErrorHandling},
    });
}])
```

But I have problem with handling error responses with `status`. I don't want normal success callback (passed into method from resource instance) to be called when error occurs, I want one global error handler, but nothing I've tried so far worked. Each time response is passed into callback. I've tried so far:

- returning $q.reject in `response` method from interceptor
- changing status code in response to 500 inside `response` method from interceptor
- changing or deleting response.resource in `response` method from interceptor

Ideal solution will be when normal callback won't be called, but my `responseError` method from interceptor will be called instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I have problem with handling error responses with status. I don't want normal success callback (passed into method from resource instance) to be called when error occurs, I want one global error handler, but nothing I've tried so far worked. Each time response is passed into callback. I've tried so far:
>
> returning $q.reject in response method from interceptor

To reject a response you don't like, use `throw`:

```
function inteceptor(httpPromise) {
    var newPromise = (httpPromise
        .then(function(response) {
                  if (dontLike) {
                      throw response;
                  } else {
                      return response;
              },
              function (eResponse) {
                  if (iLike) {
                      return eResponse;
                  } else {
                      throw eResponse;
                  };
              })
     );
     return newPromise;
};
```

To **chain** from your interceptor

```
var chainedPromise = (interceptor(httpPromise)
    .then (function (response) {
         //render data
         return response;
    }).catch (function (error) {
         console.log(error);
         throw error;
    })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found solution. I think is some bug in ngResource module.

When registered for callback like this:

```
ApiMethod.query({'get_parameter': 1}, {'post_json': 2}, function(result) {
    something...
});
```

Only solution to prevent calling callback is throwing error from ngResource interceptor. But when callback in registered in promise:

```
ApiMethod.query({'get_parameter': 1}, {'post_json': 2}).$promise.then(function(result) {
    something...
});
```

Calling callback can be prevented just by returning `$q.reject` from interceptor.

Rewriting all callback registering fixes the problem.